# Ordering nested list based on the list name i.e A1

Tags: r, list

I am trying to Order a list with nested lists by the names of the nested lists, example follows:

```
List of 12
 $ A_6 :'data.frame':   10230 obs. of  25 variables
 $ A_2:'data.frame':    10230 obs. of  25 variables 
 $ A_10:'data.frame':   10230 obs. of  25 variables
 $ A_1:'data.frame':    10230 obs. of  25 variables
 $ A_11:'data.frame':   10230 obs. of  25 variable
```

The needed outcome would be:

```
List of 12
 $ A_1 :'data.frame':   10230 obs. of  25 variables
 $ A_2:'data.frame':    10230 obs. of  25 variables 
 $ A_6:'data.frame':    10230 obs. of  25 variables
 $ A_10:'data.frame':   10230 obs. of  25 variables
 $ A_11:'data.frame':   10230 obs. of  25 variable
```

I attempted doing `order(names())` However, I cannot arrange the 1, 10, 11 correctly.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your data, but this should work. I made a dummy list to test.

```
my_list <- list(A_1 = 1, A_2 = 2, A_3 = 3, A_6 = 6, A_8 = 8, A_9 = 9, 
                A_11 = 11, A_4 = 4, A_7 = 7, A_10 = 10, A_5 = 5 )

my_list[order(as.numeric(gsub("A_", "", names(my_list))))]

$A_1
[1] 1

$A_2
[1] 2

$A_3
[1] 3

$A_4
[1] 4

$A_5
[1] 5

$A_6
[1] 6

$A_7
[1] 7

$A_8
[1] 8

$A_9
[1] 9

$A_10
[1] 10

$A_11
[1] 11
```

Comment: Thank you.. The `gsub` did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gtools::mixedorder`/`mixedsort`.

```
my_list[gtools::mixedsort(names(my_list))]
#my_list[gtools::mixedorder(names(my_list))]
```